# Modularity support with Gradle

Tags: gradle, java-platform-module-system

I understand from this link that gradle 3 enables Java 9 support but don't support modulepath.

https://blog.gradle.org/java-9-support

Also, i found this github link which talks about jdk 9 support.

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/design-docs/jdk9-support.md

Does gradle 3.5 support compilation of modular code using jdk 9? Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Per [this tweet](https://twitter.com/gradle/status/880497889457217536), Gradle 4.1 milestone 1 will run under JDK 9. That is, legacy builds will work using JDK 9.

I believe that *support* for JDK 9 modules is still in development, per comments [in this thread](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2334).